# UILabel NSAttributedString line spacing ignored on iOS7

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

So basically i have a label with a attributedString that has custom line spacing. It works as it should on iOS6 but not on iOS7 where my spacing is a bit less than the default but not even close to where it should be. Here's my code:

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes1 = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: MUSTARD_TEXT, NSFontAttributeName:[BEBAS_FONT_DEFAULT_TO_SIZE20]};
NSMutableString *aux;
if(text)
      aux = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[text uppercaseString]];
else
      aux = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"YES"];
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:aux];
[str addAttributes:textAttributes1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [aux length])];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragrahStyle setLineSpacing:-7];
[paragrahStyle setMaximumLineHeight:26];
[str addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrahStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [aux length])];

[_label setAttributedText:str];
```

And the label looks like this:

```
    _label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _label.numberOfLines = 0;
    _label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    _label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 226;
```

The space between the lines should be like 2 px which works great on iOS6 but on iOS7 the space is huge. Any ideas?

Comment: The lineSpacing property must be a non-negative value. Apple doesn't make it easy for developers to decrease line spacing. For some fonts, the default line spacing is way too big, especially for header text. I will watch this post.